# Непрерывная/цепная дробь

Tags: c

Программа вычисляет натуральный логарифм X в N итерациях с помощью цепных дробей и выводит значение в виде `cf_log(X) = CF_LOG_X`. Задаются значения в качестве аргументов `--log X N`.
Функция осуществляется cогласно нижеприведенной формуле.

[image: неделовой кот]

Есть готовая функция `cfrac_log`, она работает, но я не понимаю, как она это делает. Почему в функции `cfrac_log` переменная `z = (x - 1)/(x + 1)`, а не `z = (x + 1)/(x - 1)`. Счет начинается с последней дроби, насколько я понял. Можно ли эту функцию как-то понятнее написать?

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf, sscanf
#include <stdlib.h> // 
#include <string.h> // 
#include <math.h> // log

double cfrac_log(double x, unsigned int n){

    double cf = n;
    double z = (x - 1)/(x + 1);
    while ( n >= 1 )
    {
        double b = n*n*z*z;
        cf = (2*n - 1) - b/cf;
        n--;
    }
return (2*z)/cf; 
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if(!strcmp(argv[1], "--log")) {

        if(argc <= 3) printf("'--log' operation requires two parameters.\n");

        else {

            char *endprt;

            double x = strtod (argv[2], &endprt);
            unsigned int n = strtoul (argv[3], &endprt, 10);

            if(sscanf(argv[2], "%lg", &x) != 1 || sscanf(argv[3], "%u", &n) != 1)
                printf("'--log' operation requires two parameters.\n");

            else {
                printf( "cf_log(%lg) = %.12g\n", x, cfrac_log(x, n));
            }
        }
    }
    else printf("Unknown parameter: %s.\n", argv[1]);

 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

x = (1+z)/(1-z) => выразить "z" => z = (1-x)/(1+x)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NoRush извините, но Ваш ответ понятен только Вам.